# How to Reverse Dependency for Class Factory moved to a Library

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dependency-management, library-project, class-factory

The following code works very well when all involved classes are in the same project (`determineSubClass` is a member of `BaseClass`):

```
protected static BaseClass determineSubClass(String p1, int p2, Boolean p3) {

    BaseClass baseObj = null;
    if ( (baseObj = SubClassOne.ofType(p1, p2, p3)) != null )
      return baseObj;
    else if ( (baseObj = SubClassTwo.ofType(p1, p2, p3)) != null )
      return baseObj;
    else if ( (baseObj = SubClassThree.ofType(p1, p2, p3)) != null )
      return baseObj;
    else if ( (baseObj = SubClassFour.ofType(p1, p2, p3)) != null )
      return baseObj;
    else
      return new SubClassDefault(p1, p2, p3);
}
```

But now, I want to move the `BaseClass` to a shared Library project, in which `SubClassOne`, `SubClassTwo`, `SubClassThree` and `SubClassFour` are **not** defined in the library but rather in the applications using this library.

I could of course move `BaseClass` back to each and every application using this library, but I wonder:

- Is there a better solution?
- Is there a solution that would let me
  keep `BaseClass` in the Library
  project and eliminate the need for it
  to know about all superclasses
  derived from it?

**EDIT** (answering @ahmet alp balkan question below):

`ofType()` of each subclass does 2 things:

1. Determines, based on the content of
   String p1 and the other parameters
   p2 and p3, whether the subclass to
   be instantiated is of *its* type.
2. If the answer is positive, it
   instantiates an object of self
   subclass. Otherwise, returns null.

As for your second question, `BaseClass` at this point holds common data members and methods to all subclasses and only this single static method which is aimed at delegating the responsibility of determining subclass to be instantiated.

BTW, thanks to your question I noticed a horrible typo in my original post: "SuperClassOne" should be "SubClassOne" etc.

Comment: what does `ofType` method does and can you give us definition of `BaseClass`. I couldn't get what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: @ahmet alp balkan See my edit above. Thanks and +1 for pointing out the unclear parts in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your static `determineSubClass` method is a factory method. It should obviously not be located on the `BaseClass`, since not only the base class should not know anything about the subclasses, but in your case it can't know anything about it, since you want to locate the base class in another project. No, this method should be located in a factory class that is responsible for creating `BaseClass` instances. What you should do is define an interface (or base type) for creating `BaseClass` instances next to the `BaseType` and defines an implementation in the [composition root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277771/what-is-a-composition-root-in-the-context-of-dependency-injection) of your application. When you have multiple applications, they probably each have a different set of `BaseClass` sub types, so each application will have a different factory. When you have this construction in place, you can inject the factory into classes that need `BaseClass` instances.

It might look something like this:

```
// Shared library
public interface IBaseClassFactory
{
    BaseClass CreateNew(String p1, int p2, Boolean p3);
}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
}

// Application code
public class SubClassOne : BaseClass
{
}

public class SubClassTwo : BaseClass
{
}

// Note that this consumer depends on IBaseClassFactory.
public class SomeConsumer
{
    private IBaseClassFactory baseClassFactory;

    public SomeConsumer(IBaseClassFactory factory)
    {
        this.baseClassFactory = factory;
    }

    public void Consume()
    {
        BaseClass instance = this.baseClassFactory
            .CreateNew("foo", 0, false);

        // use instance
    }
}  

// Composition root
class BaseClassFactory : IBaseClassFactory
{
    public BaseClass CreateNew(String p1, int p2, Boolean p3)
    {
        BaseClass baseObj = null;

        if ((baseObj = SubClassOne.ofType(p1, p2, p3)) != null)
           return baseObj;
        // etc
        else
            return new SubClassDefault(p1, p2, p3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a clear and detailed answer. This is almost perfect except that `SomeConsumer` must reside in the Library. Also, who calls `SomeConsumer`'s constructor with the `factory` object? i.e. where and how that `factory` object is created? Any suggested modifications to the above?

Comment: IOW, it's the chicken & the egg situation: `SomeConsumer` relies on an **instance** `BaseClassFactory` but in my case `SomeConsumer` must reside in the Library. How do I resolve this?

Comment: @ef2011: No chicken & egg here: `SomeConsumer` depends on the `IBaseClassFactory` abstraction that will be defined in the shared library, not on the `BaseClassFactory` implementation that is defined in the composition root. Look closely at my example and see how  `BaseClassFactory` inherits/implements `IBaseClassFactory`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good practice that the base class knows about its super classes. It violates about half of OO principles ;).....

I'd move out the method to a new Class called HierarchyManager or smth like that and have the method there. You could even build some hierarchy there -> you could effectively make this method "extendable" ....

For example in library you could have:

BaseClass -> A, B (A, B subclassing BaseClass)
and some LibraryHierachyManager handling these three classes...

and then in application using it:

C, D (subclassing BaseClass or A or B)

and some ApplicationHieararchyManager doing:

```
public static BaseClass determineSubClass(String p1, int p2, Boolean p3) {
    if (baseObj = C.ofType(.....) { 
    ....


    } else {
      return LibraryHierarchyManager.determineSubClass(p1,p2, p3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure that I understand it. If there must be at least one class that knows about all subclasses, its name is really of secondary importance. What I really need to know is where this manager class should be placed: If inside the library, then it violates the same OO principles, since the library need not "know" about all the applications that will be using it. IMHO there needs to be a way to "register" new subclasses. What's the proper way of doing that?

Comment: What I am proposing is to have it in separate class and possibly even 2 - one in library, another in the main application (library one would know about all subclasses in the library and the application about all subclasses in the application). It's exactly what makes a difference - to have separate class rather than keep it  in base class - because by just having separate class(es) makes it possible to separate it out and put in application. It's like having a separate factory class (which in fact is your case I believe - the class should be named SomethingFactory because it's Factory pattern.

Comment: Potiuk Thanks + 1 for clarifying this.