# Property injection in custom membership provider using Castle

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-membership, castle-windsor, custom-membershipprovider

So far in reading about possibilities of injection to custom membership providers, I've found two possible ways to do it:

One is the following: http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/11/windsor-managed-membershipproviders.html

Here the author basically suggests to register your custom provider and then have a rather questionable windsor adapter for membership (I don't really like the way in which it instances your provider using a container it gets from `HttpApplication`, which it ultimately wraps with the windsor adapter).

This is another, similar option: http://code.google.com/p/webdotnet/source/browse/trunk/Steeg.Framework/Web/Security/MemberShipProvider.cs?r=2

Where you just override `Initialize()` and manually instance the dependencies there. At least in the first one, you don't need to instance dependencies by hand (other than the provider itself).

There are then a few which also suggest using a service locator of some kind (MVC's or otherwise)

Then I've come across ninject injecting dependencies to properties on `Membership.Provider` rather easily with something like `_kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider)`. This is much closer to what I want, keeping the composition root concept which drew me to using DI in the first place.

How can I achieve a similar result using castle?

Update: apparently this has issues with lifecycle management. 
[Inject repository to custom membership provider with Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596441/inject-repository-to-custom-membership-provider-with-ninject)

Should I go for option #1 then? At least with that I instance the provider myself. So lifecycle management shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I use the first option and it works well. I'd far prefer to have my custom membership provider not knowing anything about the container. Resolving the container is all done in a single place so it can be changed easily later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't go with implicit property injection, since the container will skip over the property if the type is not (correctly) registered, instead of failing fast (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896344/ioc-container-check-for-errors-at-compile-time/9897097#9897097)). Instead I would use the Service Locator, but write a wrapper membership provider that does not contain any logic, but simply requests a membership provider from the service locator and calls that implementation. [Jonas Gauffin](http://blog.gauffin.org) wrote [such a thing for MVC](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/a-more-structured-membershipprovider/) (using the `DependencyResolver` service locator), which is quite nice (also [available on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/griffin.mvccontrib)), but it is easy to do yourself.

Although the use of the service locator is considered an anti-pattern, please remember that the membership model must be configured through the web.config and this part of the system does not use the `DependencyResolver.Current` itself. Also writing such a `DependencyResolverMembershipProvider` is just a bit of mechanics and can be considered part of the composition root, not of the application. Calling the container inside your composition root is not a problem.