# Testing factory method with IoC container that requries register type in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

**Update**

I want to find out if the factory should be unit tested based on its usage of method, because if I want to test it, I need to register type using IoC container, Unity used in my case. If I mock the factory, it is not actuall testing the factory method.

Below is a factory class that creates instances of type based on its parameter.

```
public class CarFactory
    {

        public ICar CreateCar(string CarType)
        {
            ICar Car;

            switch (CarType)
            {
                case RepositoryType.Car1:

                    Car = Ioc.ContainerWrapper.Resolve<Car1>();

                    break;
                case RepositoryType.Car2:       
                    Car = Ioc.ContainerWrapper.Resolve<Car2>();

                    break;

                default:

                    Car = Ioc.ContainerWrapper.Resolve<Car3>();

                    break;

            }

            return Car;
        }

    }


      class Car1 
    {

        private readonly IRepository1 _IRepository1;

        public Car1(IRepository1 repository1)
        {
            _IRepository1 = repository1;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path, from my point of view.

The purpose of a factory is to create an object so they are allowed to call the Service Locator (Yes, you are still using the Service Locator anti-pattern but you are moving it from your domain to just a factory)

Reference:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki

Back to your original question, I believe you should test your factory to guarantee that you are getting the correct object depending on the parameter used, there is a debate on if this is a unit test or any kind of integration test, in my opinion it is still a unit test following this Martin Fowler article:

http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#ClassicalAndMockistTesting

This is how I would test it:

```
IRisk myRisk = new RiskFactory().CreateGoldRisk("Risk1");

myRisk.Should().NotBeNull().And.BeOfType<Risk1>();
```

Comment: Based on your advice, to test the CreateGoldRisk method, I need to register the required type, so that the factory can create the risk type, due to the fact that the factory method is using Ioc Unity????

Comment: Yes. That's the classical TDD as described by Martin Fowler, from my point of view your code looks good, you are separating the domain logic from the "wiring logic" which is great (for more info watch the Misko Hevery clean code casts http://misko.hevery.com/presentations/ specifically http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w&feature=player_embedded). Since you moved the use of the container to the factory which is valid, the only way to test it is by registering the type in the container. My advice is: separate this kind of tests in a different assembly indicating it's an integration test

Comment: Thanks. That is great stuff. I am also reading pdf of http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/. It would be great that there are books on writing testable code or clean code that you recommend too.

Comment: I just started reading this book and it seems great to me: http://books.google.com.mx/books/about/Clean_Code.html?id=dwSfGQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to prepare container suitable for this test (that is, having `Risk` classes resolvable). With your current implementation there's not much else you can do.

Of course, this raises questions whether this is unit test anymore or not, but we can assume unity is well tested and will work (ie. assuming it won't be a possible failing point of *unit test*).

That's natural drawback of having strong dependency to IoC container in your code. One might argue you can wrap container with your custom abstraction and ... and inject it? This doesn't feel right and I'm yet to see somebody doing that.

For related problem, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10260485/343266).

Comment: I did this before (injected my own container abstraction via IoC in a factory class). Nowadays, we use MEF to pass in possible candidates to the factory and integrate that with Unity, witch is a _much_ better approach in my opinion. There is absolutely no signs of the container in the factory now.

Comment: @julealgon: yep this is indeed correct approach. Having container code *leaking* into your implementation is on the verge of anti-pattern IMO. Container should *only* be present at the top level of application where objects graph is being composed.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just test that like this:

```
[SetUp]
public void setup()
{
  // code here to set up the container....
}

[Test]
public void example_test()
{
  var factory = new RiskFactory();
  var risk = factory.CreateGoldRisk("xxxx");
  Assert.True(risk is Risk1);
}
```

On a side note. You have an IOC container. A container wrapper which is then wrapped in a factory. Your architecture probably has too many layers of abstraction..