# Questions & thoughts on IoC, composition root, servicelocator, factories

Tags: c#, ioc-container, service-locator

From time to time I've been searching for a good way to use an IoC container properly, that is:

- Using the container strictly at the [composition root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277771/what-is-a-composition-root-in-the-context-of-dependency-injection).
- Not using a common ServiceLocator (or similar) to avoid testability problems.

I'm now starting a personal project for learning new stuff, it's a WPF (4.5) MVVM application that uses WCF, EntityFramework among other tecnologies, frameworks, patterns and practices, and I want to try different approaches to make good use of the container, factories and related patterns.

One of the ideas that came to my mind was to make a generic factory that can be setup at the composition root not passing the container reference around. This should avoid testability problems. Let's have for example a factory:

```
class Factory
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> Store = new Dictionary<Type,Func<object>>();

    public static void Setup<T>(Func<T> Creation)
    {
        Store.Add(typeof(T), () => Creation());
    }

    public static T Create<T>()
    {
        Func<object> func = (from p in Store where p.Key == typeof(T) select p.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        if (func != null) return (T)func();
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

So we configure it at the composition root with something like:

```
Factory.Setup(() => container.Resolve<ITest>());

Factory.Setup<ISomeWcfService>(() => new SomeWcfService());
```

And finally, to create a concrete type:

```
ITest t = Factory.Create<ITest>();
ISomeWcfService client = Factory.Create<ISomeWcfService>();
```

Now questions and thoughts:

Did I just reinvent the servicelocator pattern?

I know it is a bad idea to pass the container around so this solves that problem and it doesn't rely on a container, but does this look good or is it just a plain bad idea?

Comment: _Did I just reinvent the servicelocator pattern?_ Yes. _Is it just a plain bad idea?_ Probably.

Comment: hahaha! I still don't get the best way to obtain object instances deep down in the application, I don't want to be passing 10+ parameters nor manually maintaining a lot of factories.

Comment: Well the benefit of auto-wiring DI containers is that if you need to add a dependency deep down in the application, you only need to change that one class - since you're never manually calling `new`, no other classes need to change. Regarding manually maintaining factories, you can use `Func<TDependency>` with Autofac and some other containers. Also, check out [Autofac's delegate factories](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories), which are quite nice IMO.

Comment: "not passing the container reference around". What do you mean? When do you need to pass the container around? If you're applying the Dependency Injection principle correctly, you'll never have to 'pass the container around'.

Comment: And what about a class being instantiated away from the composition root (lazy loading) that haves a dependency on a service, should the creator of this instance be responsible for passing the dependency although he may nod need it? should I use a factory here?

Comment: Why don't you use an existing WPF framework like Caliburn.Micro which already has taken care of the IoC support?