# How to add ASP.NET MVC Controller in Spring.Net Application Context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, spring.net, griffin.mvccontrib

I am creating a plugin system for my ASP.NET MVC Application using Spring.Net IOC Framework.
I have placed my Controllers in a different assembly, I need to add these controllers to Spring.Net Application context dynamically.

Please guide me !!

I am trying to implement plugin system like following article but I want to use Spring.Net instead of Autofac.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386674/ASP-NET-MVC-3-plug-in-architecture-using-Griffin-M

Comment: what kind of problem do you have?

Answer (score -1):

I have used Spring.Net and in it i've accessed Repository objects using Application Context
Try this

```
IApplicationContext ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
            dynamic controller= ctx.GetObject("MyController");
```

where MyController is the ID of conttoller that  you've defined in your controller.xml file

```
<object
   id="MyController "
   type="Swapeteria.Web.Controllers.ItemPostController, Swapeteria.Web"
   singleton="false">
        <constructor-arg name="repository" ref="ItemRepository" />
        <constructor-arg name="bookRepository" ref="BookRepository" />
        <constructor-arg name="authorrepository" ref="authorRepository" />
        <constructor-arg name="publisherRepository" ref="PublisherRepository" />
        <constructor-arg name="itemMapper" ref="itemMapper" />
    </object>
```

Comment: -1 and the explanation why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277771/what-is-a-composition-root-in-the-context-of-dependency-injection