# Configure routes and dependency injection outside of MVC UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

We want to move our [composition root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6277806/1108891) out of our UI layer and into another project. That means moving the `Startup` class out of the UI layer. How can we configure routes when the `Startup` class is not in the UI layer's project?

We currently have this setup.

- The `DAL` depends on the `BLL`, because the `DAL` implements the `BLL` interfaces.
- The `UI` depends on the `BLL`, because the `UI` controllers call into `BLL` interfaces.
- The `UI` depends on the `DAL`, because the UI's `Startup` contains the [composition root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6277806/1108891).

Current Dependency Graph

```
+---------+ UI.xproj 
|              +     
|              |     
|              |     
|              |     
|              v     
|           BLL.xproj
|              ^     
|              |     
|              |     
|              |     
|              +     
+---------> DAL.xproj
```

Based [on this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx) and numerous examples in the [aspnet GitHub account](https://github.com/aspnet), we're wiring up our dependencies within the `UI.Startup` class. The article states:

> Register all dependencies in the application startup method, before doing anything else.

That's what we're doing in the `UI.Startup` class. What we'd like to do, though, is to move our `Startup` class into a fourth project, so that we can eliminate the dependency of the `UI` on the `DAL`.

Desired Dependency Graph

```
      +--------------------> UI.xproj 
      |                         +     
      |                         |     
      |                         |     
      |                         |     
      +                         v     
Application.xproj +--------> BLL.xproj
      +                         ^     
      |                         |     
      |                         |     
      |                         |     
      |                         +     
      +--------------------> DAL.xproj
```

Our current `UI` uses ASP.NET MVC and the routing just works, as if by magic, with two simple steps:

1. Inside `UI.Startup`, we simply call `services.AddMvc()` and `app.UseMvc()`.
2. Onto our controller we add `[Route("api/[controller]")]`.

When we run the project within Visual Studio, we can browse to `/api/my-controller/` and see the expected action result. Groovy.

In our desired setup, the `UI` will no longer have a `Startup` class, because that call will now be in the `Application`. The `Application` will not only be responsible for configuring the dependencies, it will also need to configure routes.

How can we configure the routes to point to the controllers within the `UI` layer?

([Graphs courtesy of ASCIIFlow](http://asciiflow.com/))

Answer (score 0):

Magic reigned supreme. It just worked and is really quite nice. All I had to do was:

1. Cut and paste the Startup.cs from the `UI.xproj` into the new `Application.xproj`
2. Add a dependency on `UI` into the new Application.xproj.

Voila, routes and dependency injection still all work within Startup.cs.

## Application Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        this.ConfigurePersistenceServices(services);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
        this.ConfigurePersistence(serviceProvider);
        app.Run(async context => { await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello!"); });
    }

    private void ConfigurePersistence(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var unitOfWork = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();
        unitOfWork.Create(new TodoItem("Test"));
        unitOfWork.Save();
    }

    private void ConfigurePersistenceServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddEntityFramework()
            .AddInMemoryStore()
            .AddDbContext<FarmContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryStore(persist: true);
            });
        // TODO: Use per request not singleton!
        services.AddSingleton<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

## Application project.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6-*",
    "DAL": "1.0.0-*",
    "BLL": "1.0.0-*",
    "UI": "1.0.0-*",
    "EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta6-*",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta6-*",
    "EntityFramework.InMemory": "7.0.0-beta6-*"
  }
```

## UI project.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6-*",
    "BLL": "1.0.0-*"
  }
```

## BLL project.json

```
  "dependencies": {
  }
```

## DAL project.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta6-*",
    "BLL": "1.0.0-*"
  }
```

Comment: just wondering, where you end up having your views and what's your startup project? which one has the wwwroot ?

Comment: The Application.xproj has the `Startup` and the wwwroot right now. For the time being, we don't have any views, because we're doing a REST api, but we'd put them in the UI.xproj.

Comment: I don't think that mvc will pick the views from the UI xproj without some modification on the razor engine for locating views. (can be wrong) Let me know how it goes. thanks.