# Factory Design Pattern - Which class should I use to create a Factory

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have successfully used strategy design pattern to for a Ducks Class and its Subtypes. Below is the diagram of relationships between different classes.

[image]

Now, I want to create a Factory to generate instances of different types of ducks. Should I use behavior classes (FlyBehavior and QuackBehavior) or should I use just Duck class to create a Factory class? Thanks. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you should create factory class with Duck class and based on some conditions return different Duck species.

Comment: Generally, factories should be instantiated in the [Composition Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277771/what-is-a-composition-root-in-the-context-of-dependency-injection).

Answer (score 0):

Between the options you gave, I would go with factory class to get duck instances on some options.

But I would suggest considering builder pattern here.