# How do I use dll of .net 5 class library that contain in its class Dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-5.0

In my Asp.net Core 5  API Project

I have a **serviceLayer** that the controller uses, to get data from a third layer called dataLayer.
I want to use the service layer as a DLL in different projects.

This **ServiceLayer** Contain dependency Injections like that :

```
namespace ServiceLayer
{
    public class UserService :  IUserService
    {
        IUserRepository userRepository; // (From DataLayer)
        public UserService(IUserRepository repository) : base(repository)
        {
            this.userRepository = repository;
        }
        public Users GetAllPersonsById(int id)
        {
                return userRepository.GetById(id);
        }
    }

    public interface IUserService : IService<Users>
    {
        Users GetAllPersonsById(int id);
    }
```

How can I use the method GetAllPersonsById with the DLL **ServiceLayer**

Comment: Create a class library project

Comment: ServiceLayer, is a class library. 
I want to use it in other project.

my question about how can I use it because the dependency Injections

Comment: Then import as a reference, the dependency injection is done in the DLL itself

Comment: If the class library is in the same solution as the app, just add it as a project reference (right-click References then Add References). If not, you'll have to create a nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

> can I use it because the dependency Injections

As soon as you reference the DLL / project you can use all classes the same ways as if they were in the project.

To use a class as a service:

1. Provide the service
2. Inject the service

There's a lot of documentation available, so I'll keep this short:

```
// provide in startup.cs
services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();

// Inject where you need it
MyConstructor(IUserService userService) {}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0

### Provide Extension Method

If we take a look at other libs, most of them provide a method to setup the services.

Example: Entity framework core

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{                    
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(...));
}
```

So you could:

1. In your lib, create an extension method for IServicesCollection that adds all services of your lib.
2. In the consuming project, call `services.AddMyLibServices()`.

This could look like so:

```
public static class ServicesConfiguration
{
    public static void AddDataLayer(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
        // ... same for all services of your lib
    }
```

}

Here's a tutorial with more details:
https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/24/servicecollection-extension-pattern/

## Lamar service registries

An optional and alternative approach are service registries. It's very similar to the extension methods but uses a class to do the setup. See https://jasperfx.github.io/lamar/documentation/ioc/registration/registry-dsl/

## Composition Root

You may want to read about the composition root pattern, e.g. [What is a composition root in the context of dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277771/what-is-a-composition-root-in-the-context-of-dependency-injection)

In a simple app, your startup.cs is your composition root. In more complex apps, you could create a separate project to have a single place to configure your apps services.

## Create the DLL

There are two ways to create the DLL:

- As a project in your solution (so your solution has multiple projects, each will result in a separate DLL)
- As a separate solution and as nuget package